# Can I add a specific sentence to a cell based off of another cells answer?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that will move rows based off of an answer.  Can I add update a cell with a static sentence based off of another cells answer?

For example, if X1 in Spreadsheet1 is"Yes", then it adds the sentence "Your job was successful." to cell F1 in Spreadsheet2?

Here is my script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var columnNumberToWatch = 24; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = ["Yes", "NA"];
  if ( e.range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch &&     valueToWatch.indexOf(e.range.getValue()) >=0  ) {
var sourceSheetName = "Q2 2015 v2";
var destSheetName = "2015 Backyard Badge";
var sourceRow = e.range.getRow();
var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1g3yhsACEWAT4dzAPjB-WaizmivIjnpISEoF3mxiRik4").getSheetByName(destSheetName);
var destRow = destSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
if ( destSheet.getMaxRows() < destRow) {
  destSheet.insertRowAfter(destSheet.getLastRow());
}
var columnMap = {
  'D' : 'A',
  'W' : 'B',
  'A' : 'C',
  'B' : 'D',
  'W' : 'I',
  'X' : 'J'

};
var columnList = [];
for (var column in columnMap) {
  if (columnMap.hasOwnProperty(column)) {
    columnList.push(column);
  }
};
for (var i = 0; i < columnList.length; i++) {
  var sourceRangeText = columnList[i] + sourceRow;
  var destRangeText = columnMap[columnList[i]] + destRow;
  var sr = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceRangeText);
  var dr = destSheet.getRange(destRangeText);
  var sourceVal = sr.getValue();
  dr.setValue(sourceVal);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you already have a destination sheet: `var destSheet = `.  And your code has a `setValue()` method.  Are you getting an error?  Have you looked in the VIEW menu, under EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT to see if a particular line of code failed?  There is no point in using the `insertRowAfter()` method on the last row in the spreadsheet.  The row after the last row should already be empty.

Comment: Thanks Sandy Good.  Being newer to scripting, I pieced things together and came up with that.

Comment: No. problem.  I understand.  At the very top of your code, enter this statement: `Logger.log('address: ' + e.range.getA1Notation());` and then edit a cell.  Then look under the VIEW menu, and the LOGS.  What address do you see there?

Comment: [15-06-02 11:19:35:930 CDT] address: X10

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the debugger, to step through your code one line at a time.  In order to do that, you'll need to make some changes to your code.  Hard code some values, just for testing:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var editedCol = 24; //e.range.getColumn()
  var editedValue = 99; //e.range.getValue()
  var editedRow = 10; //e.range.getRow()

  var columnNumberToWatch = 24; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = ["Yes", "NA"];
  if (editedCol == columnNumberToWatch && valueToWatch.indexOf(editedValue) >=0  ) {
```

The above code removes `e.range.method()` from some places, and puts a variable in it's place. That's so that you can debug your code.  The explanation here is to long to put into the comment section, so I'm putting it in an answer.  These changes will allow you to run your code without needing to first edit your spreadsheet.  And that is needed so that you can run the debugger.

[image: Debug]

Click a line number in the code editor so that a red dot shows up.  With the "onEdit" function in the field just to the right of the bug icon, click the bug icon.  Then click the "Step In" button to run one line of code.  View all the values in the window at the bottom.  Step through each line of code until you find an unexpected result.

Comment: I will look through it.  Thanks for your help!